# Using one column values as index to list type values in another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have data representing temperature forecast for every 3 hours period from the moment. We also know number of 3 hour periods after which the weather is needed. So, we have dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'T_forecast': [[11.98, 10.84, 8.74, 6.31, 4.52],[11.29, 7.87, 3.94, 5.02, 7.97],[16.22, 14.87, 11.31, 10.54, 10.72]
                    ,[9.77, 7.54, 5.96, 2.75, 4.99],[18.61, 16.52, 13.52, 11.62, 16.44]], 'delta_hours_divided_by_3': [3, 1,2,3,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

                            T_forecast  delta_hours_divided_by_3
0     [11.98, 10.84, 8.74, 6.31, 4.52]                         3
1      [11.29, 7.87, 3.94, 5.02, 7.97]                         1
2  [16.22, 14.87, 11.31, 10.54, 10.72]                         2
3       [9.77, 7.54, 5.96, 2.75, 4.99]                         3
4  [18.61, 16.52, 13.52, 11.62, 16.44]                         1
```

We need to create column with particular element from the list in 'T_forecast' columns.The result should be:

```
                            T_forecast  delta_hours_divided_by_3   T_by_the_shift_start
0     [11.98, 10.84, 8.74, 6.31, 4.52]                         3               8.74       
1      [11.29, 7.87, 3.94, 5.02, 7.97]                         1               11.29
2  [16.22, 14.87, 11.31, 10.54, 10.72]                         2               14.87
3       [9.77, 7.54, 5.96, 2.75, 4.99]                         3               5.96
4  [18.61, 16.52, 13.52, 11.62, 16.44]                         1               18.61
```

I can get it for particular value, with code:

```
print(df['T_forecast'][0][df['delta_hours_divided_by_3'][0]-1])

8.74
```

But I struggle creating column out:

```
df['T_by_the_shift_start']=df['T_forecast'][df['delta_hours_divided_by_3']-1]

ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Using the for loop is not an option since the original dataframe is very large and the server will choke. What can lead to solving the issue?

Comment: I think loop would still be faster..anyways are the lists in T_forecast have equal length across all rows?

Comment: Yes, 39 elements every element (forecast for 5 days from the moment approximately)

Comment: @NikitaTsekhanovich, added a solution. does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Loop solution

```
df['T_by_the_shift_start'] = [a[b - 1] for a, b in df.to_numpy()]
```

#### Non-loop solution

** lists should have same length across all rows

** This solution will perform around 2x better only on large data sets >= 500K

```
df['T_by_the_shift_start'] = np.array([*df['T_forecast']])[range(len(df)), df['delta_hours_divided_by_3'] - 1]
```

---

```
                            T_forecast  delta_hours_divided_by_3  T_by_the_shift_start
0     [11.98, 10.84, 8.74, 6.31, 4.52]                         3                  8.74
1      [11.29, 7.87, 3.94, 5.02, 7.97]                         1                 11.29
2  [16.22, 14.87, 11.31, 10.54, 10.72]                         2                 14.87
3       [9.77, 7.54, 5.96, 2.75, 4.99]                         3                  5.96
4  [18.61, 16.52, 13.52, 11.62, 16.44]                         1                 18.61
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
df['T_by_the_shift_start']=df.apply(lambda x: x['T_forecast'][x['delta_hours_divided_by_3']-1] , axis=1) 
df
```

```
    T_forecast                          delta_hours_divided_by_3    T_by_the_shift_start
0   [11.98, 10.84, 8.74, 6.31, 4.52]        3                       8.74
1   [11.29, 7.87, 3.94, 5.02, 7.97]         1                       11.29
2   [16.22, 14.87, 11.31, 10.54, 10.72]     2                       14.87
3   [9.77, 7.54, 5.96, 2.75, 4.99]          3                       5.96
4   [18.61, 16.52, 13.52, 11.62, 16.44]     1                       18.61
```